# Using backslashes in the windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, escaping, backslash

Recently I was trying to use backslashes in the windows cmd. And the cmds behaviour seems really strange to me. For testing out the cmds behaviour, I use this c# code here, which just outputs the passed in parameters:

```
namespace CsTestProject
{
    using System;

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string item in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this program with `\\\\ \\\\` as input, then the output is `\\\\ \\`.
[image]

As you can see, somehow the cmd seems to be escaping the backslashes differently based on the positioning of the backslashes.

If I add a space at the end of the input and run the program again, then the output is `\\\\ \\\\`.
[image]

It seems as if cmd escapes the last "backslash chain" if there is no other character after the last "backslash chain". It looks something like this when I express it in code:

```
if (no character after last backslash chain)
{
    escape last backslash chain
}
else
{
    do nothing
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on?
Thank you very much for your help!